# Anomaly with "Back" button when <min-sdk> used

Tags: android, button, android-manifest, manifest, back

I have encountered a very strange effect as I get near to finishing my project.  I introduced the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

into the manifest and re-ran the project in both the emulator and a phone (HTC Desire).  I noticed that the "back" button wasn't operating in a number of areas of the program.  When I put the code into debug, the `onKeyDown` listener was firing OK [and handed off ok to `super.onKeyDown(..)`] whereas the `onBackPressed` listener wasn't firing at all.

When I removed the `uses-sdk` entry from the manifest all returned to normal.  Can anyone explain please because I really need to use the `min-sdk` statement.

Update:
I have experimented right down to `min-sdk="1"` (the default value) and the effect is the same.  I then removed the min-sdk value and used the `target-sdk` value instead with EXACTLY THE SAME consequences i.e. the back button won't work in all places.  Simply removing the tag `<uses-sdk  .... />` completely fixes the effect but leaves me with the problem of needing to declare a minimum sdk value before I deploy.  Please help, someone, anybody...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we met the same problem.
I use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832861/android-back-key-by-software) to simulate a soft back button, but when "min-sdk" is added, the button doesn't work. It seems like "dispatchKeyEvent" and "min-sdk" are in conflict. I used "onBackPressed" instead, it works fine for me.

```
public class BackButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Activity host = (Activity) v.getRootView().getContext();
        host.onBackPressed();
    }
} 
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
back.setOnClickListener(new BackButtonClickListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use onKeyDown?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // do some stuff
    return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks kazufukurou but have already tried that.  Although the onKeyDown listener fires ok I'm relying on Android OS to perform the reverse navigation in a number of places [rather than explicitly calling finish()].  The problem seems to be that the OS isn't handling the "Back" navigation in all cases.  And I AM including the super.onKeyDown(...) statement.