# Call the hardware back button programmatically?

Tags: android

I know that one can overwrite the Back Button functionality in Android, but I was wondering if there was a method or anything I could call that would functionally do the same thing as pressing the hardware button.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can send the back button press to the system like this

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

Or you can override the back button press and call

```
finish();
```

on your Activity. That basically does the same thing as the generic back button.

Comment: Doesn't work in my code...tells me to change it to ACTION_DOWN, and KEYCODE_BACK don't exist, what would I need to import for them to be found?

Comment: Try using KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :)

Comment: Thanks @jimmithy I updated the solution. Hopefully that was the correct answer you were looking for :)

Comment: This did not work for me. But found this workaround that others might find useful too:

dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891899/555856

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. You are literally dispatching a key event when the button is pressed down and then up. Did you try removing just the ACTION_DOWN event and see if it still works?

Answer (score 22):

Just call `this.onBackPressed();` in Activity.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: This one is the best answer, as simply calling finish doesn't trigger onBackPressed like the real back button does.  If the activity is doing extra stuff there it'll be missed.

Comment: But like if there is any dialog over activity then it will close activity, and real button doesn't do that.

Comment: @NehaK In that case, you can override onBackPressed() If the dialog is showing then dismiss it first.

Answer (score 8):

If you want just "press" hardware button,
create service extended from `AccessibilityService`:

```
class ExampleAccessService:AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    }
    
    fun doAction(){
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_QUICK_SETTINGS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)
    }
}
```

*Call `doAction()` where you want action*

Add to `Manifest`:

```
<application
...
    <service
        android:name=".ExampleAccessService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="Name of servise" // it will be viewed in Settings->Accessibility->Services
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
    </service>
...
</application>
```

**accessibility_service_config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="false"
    android:description="your description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="your app package, ex: ex: com.example.android"
    android:settingsActivity="your settings activity ex: com.example.android.MainActivity" />
```

for more info look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service